# traversing memory owned by a unique_ptr gives segfault

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

In order not to have to remember to delete, we are using unique_ptr to manage the memory.
We were under the impression that we can write and read in the memory, just that deletion is up to the smart pointer. However, the following code crashes on i=7220 with a segfault.

What is wrong?

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  const uint32_t n = 40000000;
  uint64_t*p = new uint64_t[n]; // this works, but we have to delete the memory or leak
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    p[i] = i;

  unique_ptr<uint64_t> mem = make_unique<uint64_t>(n);

  uint64_t* p1 = mem.get();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // this crashes at i=7220
    p1[i] = i;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: After applying [the fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67927639/10147399), you can replace the loop with [std::iota](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
unique_ptr<uint64_t> mem = make_unique<uint64_t>(n);
```

This allocates *one* `uint64_t` dynamically with the value `n`.

You want:

```
unique_ptr<uint64_t[]> mem = make_unique<uint64_t[]>(n);
```

This specialization allocates an *array* of `uint64_t` with `n` elements, and has an `operator[]` overload which makes the below possible:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    mem[i] = i;
```

So, there's no need to do `uint64_t* p1 = mem.get();`

Answer (score 5):

`unique_ptr<uint64_t>` is a pointer to a single `uint64_t` value. In order to make it store an array you need to use *array of unknown bound* syntax:

```
unique_ptr<uint64_t[]> mem = make_unique<uint64_t[]>(n);
```

or just

```
auto mem{make_unique<uint64_t[]>(n)};
```

Note that this variant overloads operator [] so there is no need to create an intermediate raw pointer `uint64_t* p1 = mem.get();`

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the fix other answers mentioned, you likely **don't** want to use `make_unique` here. `make_unique` will zero-out every single element (40 million ints!) and you immediately overwrite them. Your options are to use `make_unique_for_overwrite` which requires C++20, or to use `new`:

```
#include <cstdint>  // for uint64_t
#include <memory>   // for unique_ptr, unique_ptr<>::pointer
#include <numeric>  // for iota

int main() {
  auto const n = 40'000'000;
  auto const p = std::unique_ptr<std::uint64_t[]>{new std::uint64_t[n]};
  std::iota(p.get(), p.get() + n, 0);
}
```